# How can I find my Pi's external (public) IP address?

Tags: web-server

I cannot seem to figure out what my external IP address is on my Pi. I believe I will need to know it in order for me to allow other people to send information to the web server I have that is running off of my Raspberry Pi. My Pi's web server is currently not online. I do not know if this has anything to do with why I cannot find my external IP address.

**How can I find my Pi's external IP address?**

Answer (score 26):

There is a cool way of getting your public IP on Raspberry PI.

```
curl icanhazip.com
```

As **lenik** suggested, you need to forward port 80 from router to your Raspberry PI in order to have public web server.

Comment: If you want to force ipv4 you can use ipv4.icanhazip.com or the same for ipv6.

Answer (score 6):

external address of your pi is the same as the external address of your router. please use your browser to access [whatismyip.com](http://whatismyip.com) to find out the exact value.

btw, other people would not be able to access your pi, unless you configure your router to forward requests to the port 80 to your pi address.

Answer (score 2):

If your ISP give you a dynamic IP address (which most home lines do), then your external IP will change at random times. it is still possible to reach it, (if your router is set to forward port 80 like mentioned earlier). you can use a service like [noip.com](http://www.noip.com/)

This way you can ask people to find  you at youraccount.no-ip.org and it will point at your raspberry, no matter what the actuall ip is.

to do this, first step is to create an account at noip.com (it is free), then install the client for raspberry,

```
wget http://www.no-ip.com/client/linux/noip-duc-linux.tar.gz
```

a good tutorial for doing this can be found [here](https://www.noip.com/support/knowledgebase/install-ip-duc-onto-raspberry-pi/)

Answer (score 1):

Use any [what is my ip](http://whatismyip.live) website to get your external IP address such as whatismyip.live whatismyip.com whatismyipaddress.com etc.

Answer (score -1):

It's easy:
In console (LXTerminal) on the pi type this:

> ifconfig eth0

and it will come up with a load of info and you have to look for the thing that says "inet addr:", after this is your ip

Will :3

Comment: I believe this just returns your local ip address.